# UIProgressView value from plist inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass a number from a plist to a `UIProgressView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. So far, I have done this:

`myUIProgressView.progress =[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"myUIProgressViewValue"];`

However, when doing this I get an error: `Assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'id'`

How can I fix this?

Also, the value coming from the plist is not a decimal (because the number is used more than once), but instead a whole number. I need to somehow add a . before the number within that piece of code above, but I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Print `[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"myUIProgressViewValue"]`. It's like this `.100`?

Comment: The second issue I have is the value in the plist that I am pulling is `8`. But the `UIProgressView` needs to see `.8`. So, how do I add the `.` to `valueForKey:@"myUIProgressViewValue"`?

Comment: Do you mean `0.8` or just `value / 10`?

Comment: @Bannings I suppose both could work, right? All I need is for the `UIProgressView` to effectively see `0.8`, so dividing the original number by 10 should work just fine.

Comment: Try this: `myUIProgressView.progress = [[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"myUIProgressViewValue"] floatValue] / 10;`

Comment: @Bannings Your solution works perfectly. Once you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it solved your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myUIProgressView.progress = [[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"myUIProgressViewValue"] floatValue] / 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
myUIProgressView.progress =[[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] floatValue]valueForKey:@"myUIProgressViewValue"];
```